# How can you stop the mobile phone charging using an app API

Tags: android, ios, mobile, battery

Is there a way to detect the percentage charge of a battery and then stop the phone charging when at X%?

So far I have read the battery functions for Android are READ ONLY, but the posts were quite old.  Has there been any new changes that would allow this?

If not is this possible on iPhone or Windows Phones using native API?

Answer (score 2):

> Has there been any new changes that would allow this?

No.

Comment: what about on iPhone or Windows phone?